# Struggling to get the cell index path at the centre of collectionview

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I'm trying to get the indexpath of the cell in the collectionview like so using an extension

**Code in extension**

```
extension InfiniteCollectionView
{

    var centerPoint : CGPoint {
        get {
            return CGPoint(x: self.contentOffset.x + (CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) * 0.5) , y: self.contentOffset.y + (CGRectGetWidth(self.bounds) * 0.5))
        }
    }

    var centerCellIndexPath: NSIndexPath?{

            return self.indexPathForItemAtPoint(self.centerPoint)
    }
}
```

So i can get the center indexpath like so

```
print(collectionVw.centerCellIndexPath)
```

But this keeps on returning nil which i can't seem to figure out why, it's worth noting that the extension is in a class called **InfiniteCollectionView** which is set as the custom class on a collectionview rather than a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

"indexPathForItemAtPoint will return nil if no item was found at the specified point", your calculation for center point can return a point in space, so use indexPathsForVisibleItems.
The documentation also suggests to use layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:
"Use this method to retrieve the layout information for a particular item. You should always use this method instead of querying the layout object directly."